# What is the meaning of "happening cities"

Tags: meaning

I am looking for the definition of "happening cities" but I didn't find it anywhere, for example, "Which are the most happening cities of India" or "20 Reasons Tulsa Is Actually A Happening City". If someone can explain it and what synonyms could substitute the meaning?

Thanks

Comment: I think the expression refers to cities with exciting things happening in them: local festivals, national concert tours, and an exciting night life. So synonyms might include vibrant or exciting.

Answer (score 3):

> #### Happening
>
> *informal adjective*
>
> - offering much stimulating activity

Synonyms: [flourishing](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flourishing), [busy](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/busy), [hopping](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hopping), [lively](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lively), [vibrant](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vibrant), [alive](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alive), [thriving](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thriving)...and [hip](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hip)!

([MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/happening))

Comment: It is itself a very 'hip' term.